# Windows Server 2008 R2 > which Product?

Tags: windows-server

1. Which Windows Server 2008 R2 to download for SP2010?

Comment: If you have a different question, PLEASE ask separately. Now my answer does not relate to your question.

Also, your question is now off topic for SharePoint.SE

Comment: @Tim: You have answered my question. I accidentally deleted original post instead of adding key piece to it. I fixed the question. Thanks Tim....

Comment: Good to hear. Have fun with SharePoint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need any language specific versions, you'll want

> Windows Server 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1 (x64) - DVD (English)

This contains all the different versions (Enterprise, Datacenter, Web, Standard, etc). Enterprise or Standard should be more than sufficient.